# Media View in cakePHP

Tags: cakephp

Hi i implemented file download functionality in cakePHP frame work using MediaView for few 
  reasons i passed one parameter through URL that parameter is displayed along with the file 
  name i need to remove the URL parameter, i tried but failed please helop me.

My code for downloading a file

```
$fileExtn = explode('.', $this->contentItem['file_path']);
        $url = $this->contentItem['file_path'];
        $urlArr = explode('/', $url);           
        $fileExtn = end($fileExtn);
        if(in_array($fileExtn, $this->MEDIAMAP)) {
            $fileExtn = str_replace('.', '', $fileExtn);
            if(!empty($urlArr)) {
                $fileName = end($urlArr);
                $fileNameWOExtn = explode('.', $fileName);
                //$fileNameWOExtn = $fileName[0];
                $fileNameWOExtn = $fileName;
                unset($urlArr[count($urlArr)-1]);
                $url = implode(DS, $urlArr);
            }
            $this->view = 'Media';
            $params = array(
                    'id' => $fileName,
                    'name' => $fileNameWOExtn,
                    'download' => false,
                    'extension' => $fileExtn,  // must be lower case
                    'path' => APP . 'views' . DS . 'static'. $url .DS  // don't forget terminal 'DS'                        
            );
            $this->set($params);
```

My URL is like this : /uploads/leave_policy_leave_policy_tasks_v1.3.xlsx

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using.

Comment: Removing all your debugging output (LogUtil::$logg etc) would also make it more readable :D. One can focus on the real code then.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression to look for the last `.` char, such as

```
preg_match("/(.*?)(\.)(\w*)$/", $filepath, $path_parts);
```

You'll also want to leverage the functionality of the `Folder` and `File` objects that come with CakePHP.